# Friend can't join Dedicated Server over VPN

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I am a bit confused since I normally play with a friend over a VPN. This works totally fine for Vanilla Minecraft, but we added a huge Modpack for Minecraft 1.16.5 and sometimes the game freezes and or straight up crashes. Therefore I set up a server with a few spare parts lying around and it works fine, I can see/join the server yet my friend who connects over a VPN to my network cannot. We checked his settings and he receives an IP Address from my Router, also I can ping his device without any problem. The server is set up to run only on the local network, I entered the same IP Address as the device it is currently running on.

So my question is: Why does it not work and how do I make it functional?

**Information**:
The server and the clients are running the exact same version of Minecraft Forge, all config-files are the same, all Mods are the same, all Mods are up-to-date, Port-Forwarding is already set in Router, ISP won't interfere.

1. MC-Server / Linux / 192.168.2.151
2. Client 1  / Windows / 192.168.2.103
3. Client 2  / Windows / 192.168.2.122

[image: Current Network Diagramm]

Comment: Showing you are 90% there doesn't make it a 'dumb question'. You can be 99% there, if there is a wall there, you are stuck. And I personally don't think it would be a SO question.

Comment: First try to run `tracert 192.168.2.151` on you `Client 2`-PC, and post the outputs here.
this command should show you, what route the network packets are gooing.

Comment: The fact that you had no problems with vanilla Minecraft doesn't work in your favour, though, I'm afraid. What other differences are there between both installations? Could it be a performance issue? Can your friend join outside of a VPN?